# Пропасть втуне

Tags: этимология

Искала - вроде, этого вопроса раньше не задавали.
Есть выражение "пропасть втуне", то есть, потратить что-то впустую. Как я понимаю, изначально В было предлогом, а не приставкой. А что же тогда такое "туна" и почему в нее все напрасно пропадает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шанский говорит, что это сращение: въ туне («напрасно, даром»),где тунь «безвозмездный»,как всуе.Сравним: Тунеядец - ест даром,напрасно, т.е. не возвращая пользу(безвозмездно).

http://etymology-dictionary.info/%D

Поэтому в словаре поговорок указано значение Оставаться втуне = Не приносить никакой пользы, не находить применения. http://enc-dic.com/russaying/Vtune-4450.html

Answer (score 2):

Вот, например: Белор. ту́нны – то же, болг. тун "ложный", ту́не "напрасно".

Answer (score 0):

Происходит от неустановленной формы, родственной др.-русск., ст.-слав. туне, ... белор. ту́нны – то же, болг. тун "ложный", ту́не "напрасно", ...

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B5